# how to change the default div on backbone?

Tags: backbone.js

I´m starting to get familiar with backbone.js  but how can I wrap the objects
in something diferent than a div ? can this be done? I want to make this on my view setup.

Comment: This is pretty clearly spelled out in [the manual](http://backbonejs.org/#View) you know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily override the default tag by setting the tagName property to whatever you want

```
var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({tagName: 'li'});
var listView = new ListView();
console.log(listView.el); // logs <li></li>
```

check out the [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/)

Comment: I'm glad :) please if you find this answer useuful consider upvoting and mark as accepted so it remains useful to other users on the site ;)